# RapidJson - fix a bug in writing

Tags: json, rapidjson

I'm using the latest version of RapidJson I found and I got now a strange warning when compiling, not shown before.
I use this approach to write a Document in a Json using RapidJson:

```
GenericStringBuffer< UTF8<> > buffer;
Writer< GenericStringBuffer< UTF8<> > > writer(buffer);     
doc.Accept(writer);
```

Now, I got this warning:

> ...\rapidjson\document.h(553): warning C4800: 'unsigned int': forcing
>   value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning) 
>   ...\firsttimescene.cpp(583): see the reference to the instance of
>   function template 'const rapidjson::GenericValue
>   &rapidjson::GenericValue::Accept>(Handler
>   &) const' being compiled
>             with
>             [
>                 Encoding=rapidjson::UTF8<>,
>                 OutputStream=rapidjson::GenericStringBuffer>,
>                 Handler=rapidjson::Writer>>
>             ]

Do someone can help me? It seems everything is working but I'm a little bit afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the bug in Document.h by PAH on the new release: https://github.com/pah/rapidjson